# Chrome Print Dialog won't execute a separate JavaScript function until the dialog is cancelled or printed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I'm trying to execute a tracking call on on a click event that also executes `window.print()`. I've put the tracking call first but it won't execute until the dialog box is closed.

Firefox and IE execute everything in order. The issue seems unique to Chrome.
I've consoled some text and they show up in the right order, but the network doesn't show the tracking call until I close the dialog box.

Anyone know how to get around this?

```
<script>
function printTrack(){
    _satellite.track('something');
    window.print();
}
</script>

<button id="print-button" onclick="javascript:printTrack()">Print</button>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Are you doing this in a new window with `window.open()`. I've found lots of hits in google about `window.print()` in the child window blocking the parent window. It's a known bug.

Comment: No window.open...

function printTrack(){
   _satellite.track('blah');
window.print();

}

It's pretty simple. I've set a timeout on the tracking call and that didn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by a tracking call? BTW, the "tracking" tag says **DO NOT USE**, why did you use it?

Comment: @Barmar, what do you mean, "DO NOT USE?"

Comment: Hover over the tag, it says: *DO NOT USE, since is considered too generic. Consider using a more specific tag such as `[video-tracking]` or `[bug-tracking]` instead.*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using a promise:

```
function printTrack(pn) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(_satellite.setVar('pdf_name', pn), 
            _satellite.track('pdf_print'));
        });
    }

    printTrack(printName).then(function (result) {
        window.print();
    });
```